# pandas | drop_duplicates(subset=['col1', 'col2', 'col3']) not dropping based on given column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to drop duplicated rows in dataframe by using .drop_duplicates with a subset list so that it only drops the rows that has the same value in the given column names. But for some reason, it didn't drop all of them.

This is the dataframe before dropping...
[image]

This is the code that I used to drop the rows...
`df_combined.drop_duplicates(subset = ['Anonymized_ID', 'COURSE', 'GRADE'], keep='last', inplace=True)`

This is the dataframe after dropping...
[image]

I was expecting to see only two rows after dropping since they have same values for the specified column

Comment: it could be that there are whitespaces in the data. check Course and Grade columns that results after the drop_duplicates

Comment: Like @Naveed said, it is better if you can print the individual values from each of the required column for id=9?

Comment: @yessspink, let me know if the answer has helped you or not

Comment: @PrakashDahal still not dropping the duplicates after .strip() any other possibilities that is causing this?

Comment: @PrakashDahal not sure if it's good practice but I found a way to bypass it. The issue seems to be caused by the white space. So since the .strip() is not working, I use .replace instead. And the .drop_duplicates works after that!